# Getting left column to resize with CSS

Tags: css

I am working on a simple redesign for a project I did awhile back, just for practice. I have a left column that remains a certain size no matter what I seem to do. When the content in the main area becomes too great, the left column looks cut off. How do I get this column to extend with the content of the page? Here is the css I have for my containers and the column:

```
#outerWrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
    min-width: 760px;
    text-align: left; 
    width: 80%;
}
#outerWrapper #header {
    background-color: #8ab573;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #628152; 
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
}
#outerWrapper #contentWrapper #leftColumn1 {
    background-color: #eef6ed;
    border-right: solid 1px #8ab573; 
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 24%;
    height: auto;
}

#outerWrapper #contentWrapper #content {
    margin: 0 0 0 26%; 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
}

#outerWrapper #contentWrapper .clearFloat {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}
#outerWrapper #footer {
    background-color: #eef6ed;
    border-top: solid 1px #8ab573;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
```

Thanks for any suggestions, I know it's really simple I'm just having code block I guess :/

Comment: and the html? make a fiddle

Comment: Um, the outer wrapper is set to 80%. The left column is set to 24%. I don't see what anyone would need the HTML for. All I'm trying to do is figure out what property I need to use in the leftcolumn selector to have it resize the height automatically when the main page content is extended.

Comment: If you are talking about height, you might want to consider flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox